# Symmetric linear least-squares solution ${\bf X} {\bf A} = {\bf B}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, least-squares

Given the wide matrices ${\bf A} \in {\Bbb R}^{n \times m}$ and ${\bf B} \in {\Bbb R}^{p \times m} $, where $m > n > p$, form an overdetermined linear system in ${\bf X} \in {\Bbb R}^{p \times n}$

$${\bf X} {\bf A} = {\bf B}.$$

In the next step, I want to use the solution of this problem to obtain ${\bf X}^+ {\bf D} {\bf X}$, where $\bf D$ is a diagonal matrix. I hope to find one $\bf X$ which renders the matrix product ${\bf X}^+ {\bf D} {\bf X}$ symmetric.

---

**Motivation**

I have a number of state-space systems with different dimensions which I want to express all on a basis of the same size. Suppose we have two state vectors, namely,

- the reference state vector ${\bf s}_{\text{ref}} \in {\Bbb R}^n$
- the state vector ${\bf s}_k \in {\Bbb R}^p$ that I want to express in the higher-dimensional state space ${\Bbb R}^n$

I find ${\bf s}_k = {\bf X} {\bf s}_{\text{ref}}$. The new state space system becomes ${\bf X} \dot{{\bf s}}_{\text{ref}} = {\bf D}  {\bf X} {\bf s}_{\text{ref}}$. Isolating the left side yields then $ \dot{{\bf s}}_{\text{ref}} = {\bf X}^+ {\bf D} {\bf X} {\bf s}_{\text{ref}}$. A least-squares solution can be found by taking the pseudoinverse as ${\bf X} = {\bf B} {\bf A}^{+}$. However, this does not maintain symmetry afterwards. Your consideration is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are many typos, please recheck your question and edit it to make sure it's understandable. (1) symmetric or orthogonal? (2) what is that minimum problem? Over which set with which constraints? (3) $B$ vs. $Y$. (4) Is that absolute value meant to be a norm? Which one?

Comment: Thanks, @FedericoPoloni for pointing this out. I think I clarified (1),(3) and (4). However, for (2) I am not sure how to pose the problem. I merely would like to find one least squares solution for X which also fulfills this constraint.

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but the dimensions still do not add up. $X$ is $p\times n$, so $X^TX$ is $n\times n$ with rank $p$ and cannot be equal to the identity.

Comment: You are right. The dimensionality is not correct. I chose this condition because I subsequently want the product $X^+ D X$ to be symmetric for some diagonal matrix D.  I changed this in the question.

Comment: In general, ${\bf X}^+ {\bf X} \neq {\bf I}$. Perform some experiments with MATLAB using `pinv`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have an [Orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem), which can be solved via SVD. I suggest you start from this name for a literature search.

Comment: Is $\bf X$ even square?

Comment: No $\bf X$ is not square. Also, $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ have only the same number of columns.